# Matlab code after compilation

Tags: matlab

I am totally a newbie in Matlab
I want to ask that when we write a program in Matlab software or IDE and save it with a 
.m (dot m) file and then compile and execute it, then that .m (dot m) file is converted into which file? I want to know this because i heard that matlab is platform independent and i did google this but i got converting matlab file to C, C++ etc 
Sorry for the silly question and thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/compiler/index.html.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matlab is an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language). So in most cases there is no persistent intermediate form. However, there is an encrypted intermediate form called [`pcode`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/pcode.html) and there are also the MATLAB compiler and MATLAB coder which delivers code in other high level languages such as C.

**edit:**
`pcode` is not generated automatically and should be platform/version independent. But it's major purpose is to encrypt the code, not to compile it (although, it does some partial compilation). To use `pcode`, you still need the MATLAB environment installed, so in many ways it acts like interpreted code.

But from your follow-up question I guess you don't quite understand how MATLAB works. The code gets interpreted (although with a bit of Just-In-Time Compilation), so there is no need for a persistent intermediate code file: the actual data structures representing your code are maintained by MATLAB. In contrast to compiled languages, where your development cycle is something like "write code, compile & link, execute", the *compilation* (actually: interpretation) step is part of the execution, so you end up with "write code, execute" in most of the cases.

Just to give you some intuitive understanding of the difference between a compiler and an interpreter. A compiler translates a high level language to a lower level language (let's say machine code that can be executed by your computer). Afterwards that compiled code (most likely stored in a file) is executed by your computer. An interpreter on the other hand, interprets your high level code piece by piece, determining what machine code corresponds to your high level code during the runtime of the program and immediately executes that machine code. So there is no real need to have a machine code equivalent of your entire program available (so in many cases an interpreter will not store the complete machine code, as that is just wasted effort and space).

You could look at interpretation more or less as a human would interpret code: when you try to manually determine the output of some code, you follow the calculations line by line and keep track of your results. You don't generally translate that entire code into some different form and afterwards execute that code. And since you don't translate the code entirely, there is no need to persistently store the intermediate form.

As I said above: you can use other tools such as [MATLAB coder](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/matlab-coder/index.html) to convert your MATLAB code to other high languages such as C/C++, or you can use the [MATLAB compiler](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/compiler/index.html) to compile your code to executable form that depends on some runtime libraries. But those are only used in very specific cases (e.g. when you have to deploy a MATLAB application on computers/embedded devices without MATLAB, when you need to improve performance of your code, ...)

**note:** My explanation about compilers and interpreters is a quick comparison of the archetypal interpreter and compiler. Many real-life cases are somewhere in between, e.g.  Java generally compiles to (JVM) bytecode which is then interpreted by the JVM and something similar can be said about the .NET languages and its CLR.

Comment: Thanks Egon.......But i want to ask that this 'p' code gets generated automatically when we execute our .m(dot m) file or we have to do it explicitly.

Comment: `p` code isn't generated automatically, but I suggest you stay away from `pcode` as a beginner. You'd might want to take a look at the distinction between compiled and interpreted languages if my explanation above is not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks Egon for your detailed explanation.It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since MATLAB is an interpreter, you can write code and just execute it from the IDE, without compilation.

If  you want to deploy your program, you can use the MATLAB compiler to create an stand-alone executable or a shared library that you can use in a C++ project. On Windows, MATLAB code would compile to an .EXE file or a .DLL file, respectively.