# Why does the first call to a Matlab DLL take much longer than subsequent calls?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I call from my C++ code a DLL that was written in MATLAB.
I observe a strange effect: the first call takes much more time that the next calls.
It takes 3-4 times more.
Is it normal?
Is it possible to do something with it?

Comment: How are you making the calls in your c++ code?

Comment: A perfectly fine question. Probably non-Matlab users closed it due to misunderstanding.

Comment: My understanding is the only way to avoid this is to convert the Matlab code to C or C++ code using [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com.au/products/matlab-coder/index.html) and then compile it from there. As @NominSim points out, "compiled" Matlab code isn't actually compiled - there is a good SO answer on this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636267/matlab-code-after-compilation)

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is normal, the delay comes from starting up the [MATLAB Runtime Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/index.html). This is what runs the MATLAB code from the dll that you created through MATLAB. The initial startup cannot be avoided AFAIK, but you can maybe add a dummy call to the DLL when your application begins in order to avoid the "cost" later.

Comment: Since the question is locked, I will add this as a comment. The are two types of delays - the first when you run your application in the first time *ever* in this computer, then the ZIP file is extracted and the MCR is launched. The second type is when you already ran this application once. Then, only the MCR is loaded.

Comment: I thought that delay from starting Matlab Runtime Compiler is somewhere in call to mclInitializeApplication or <functionName>Initialize().

Comment: If I have several MATLAB functions in several DLL's does it mean , that such delay will be on the first call to each function ?